# Confusing Reputation Time stamp Sorting

Tags: support

Today I was looking at some reputation I gained last night.

My first stop was to go to the reputation tab where I noticed some strange behavior to how the timestamps are sorted.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above `Yesterday` is sorted from earliest to latest time (which is fine)

Confusingly `2 Days ago` is sorted in the opposite direction going from Latest to earliest

And finally `Jan 11` is just a mixture of both...

So what is going on?

I am very confused as to how they are being sorted and its hurting my head trying to figure it out

Comment: It could just be that no sort is happening and you are getting the records as they are served up from the database.

Comment: @NathanOliver I considered that that might be the case but then I don't understand how they are ending up in that order from the database

Comment: In the top right you see it's ordered on "post", I guess it's ordering on the time the question/answer was posted?

Comment: @Thaillie You're correct. Chaning Post to Time does sort the reputation by TimeStamp. I guess the follow up question is what does sort by `Post` mean / Relate to?

Comment: Looks like it's sorted by reputation to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are sorted by most rep given per action. As seen in my reputation tab, https://stackoverflow.com/users/4052384/pythonmaster?tab=reputation, my rep changes is listed from greatest postive change to greatest negative change per day. As for you, here is what happens:

- Yesterday

  - The top item is an upvote that gives you 10 rep
  - The final item is an upvote that gives you 5 rep, which is 5 rep less than 10 rep
- 2 days ago

  - You got two upvotes worth the same so then they are ordered by time (I think)
- January 11

  - You got an upvote that gives you 10 rep
  - Next is an edit which gives you 2 rep, 8 less than 10 rep
  - Finally you got 0 rep from accepting your own answer, which clearly is less than 8 and 10.

Comment: This sounds like the most likely explanation. Thank you. This does lead me to think SO could have used a better word than `Post` to describe how they are sorted, if this is the case.